# How to submit a Angular form in parts and together

Tags: angular, typescript

How to submit the form in parts and together.
I have one big form. And a dozen different key combinations. Which need to be sent when re-editing fields on separate requests to the server.
In addition, these parts are used in different parts of the application.
How do I make the forms independent, but at the same time so that I can dine them when needed. And send one big one.
For understanding, I drew two small ones, for example.
I am trying to create one module so that there is no code duplication. But I don't understand how to split small forms into child components. And so that you can edit and send these components with separate send buttons. And at the same time there was one button that sends everything.

```js
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
   this.form1 = this.fb.group({
     age: [20],
     name: ['asdas']
   });

   this.form2 = this.fb.group({
    adress: ['20'],
    city: ['Kiev']
  });

  this.form3 = this.fb.group({
    age: [20],
    name: ['asdas']
    adress: ['20'],
    city: ['Kiev']
 });
  }

  public onSubmit1(): void {
  // for form 1
  }
  public onSubmit2(): void {
    // for form 2
  }
  public onSubmit3(): void {
      // for form 3
  }
```

Comment: put all forms in an object `const forms = {
    form1: {

    },
    form2: {

    },
    form3: {

    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can just merge the form values into one object. See the `submitAllForms()` at the bottom.

```js
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
   this.form1 = this.fb.group({
        age: [20],
        name: ['asdas']
   });

   this.form2 = this.fb.group({
        adress: ['20'],
        city: ['Kiev']
   });

   this.form3 = this.fb.group({
        age: [20],
        name: ['asdas']
        adress: ['20'],
        city: ['Kiev']
    });
}

...

public submitAllForms(): void {
    // values is a new object, that holds the values of all forms
    const values = {...this.form1.values, ...this.form2.values, ...this.form3.values}
}
```